# Reviewing edit on question causes bug if the question gets edited

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I came across a question today that had really bad formatting problems and should really be closed. However, there was a pending edit on it so I opened up the edit on the question, which causes the pop up window and greys the background out.

As I was reviewing it, Reject and Edit, and mid edit another user edited the question. This caused the edit window to disappear and the question refresh i.e. I could see the edit changes and the editor, time etc. Everything was up to date. I didn't get a popup, or bar, saying that the question had been edited one times or anything similar so was left wondering what had happened.

More importantly though the screen remained greyed out and I had to click the screen to go back to it looking normal. See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Is this a bug?

I am running IE 11.0.14393.0 on Windows 10.